# Implementar um "contador" de resultados

Tags: java, swing, tablemodel

Eu tenho uma tela de pesquisa/consulta de cadastros e quando eu faço a consulta, por exemplo, de todos países, um *label* "seta" quantos países encontrou, (por exemplo 19 países encontrados).

Porém, se dentro desses resultados eu digitar uma letra pra corresponder a um pais, por exemplo, letra "B" para Brasil, e tiver apenas Brasil, ele não atualiza a quantidade de resultados para 1.

Estou pegando a quantidade de resultados com o método `getRouwCount`, pois cada linha setada na tabela, equivale a um resultado diferente.

Aqui tem um exemplo muito básico, mais que já ilustra o problema.

```
package teste;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Teste extends JFrame {

    private String[] colunas
            = {"Country", "Capital", "Population in Millions", "Democracy"};

    private Object[][] dados = {
        {"USA", "Washington DC", 280, true},
        {"Canada", "Ottawa", 32, true},
        {"United Kingdom", "London", 60, true},
        {"Germany", "Berlin", 83, true},
        {"France", "Paris", 60, true},
        {"Norway", "Oslo", 4.5, true},
        {"India", "New Delhi", 1046, true}
    };

    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(dados, colunas);
    private JTable tabela = new JTable(model);

    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(tabela.getModel());

    private JTextField barraPesquisa = new JTextField();
    private JButton botao = new JButton("OK");

    private JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public Teste() {
        add(x());
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JComponent x() {
        JPanel painelX = new JPanel();
        painelX.setLayout(null);

        painelX.add(barraPesquisa);
        barraPesquisa.setBounds(20, 10, 270, 27);
        painelX.add(botao);
        botao.setBounds(300, 10, 65, 27);

        barraPesquisa.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = barraPesquisa.getText();

                //model.setRowCount(0); // limpar as linhas
                label.setText(model.getRowCount() + " resultados encontrados");
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                    model.getRowCount();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = barraPesquisa.getText();
                label.setText(model.getRowCount() + " resultados encontrados");
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            }
        });

        tabela.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

        painelX.add(tabela);
        tabela.setBounds(5, 100, 500, 150);

        painelX.add(label);
        label.setBounds(10, 250, 150, 30);
        label.setText(model.getRowCount() + " resultados encontrados!");

        painelX.setBounds(1, 1, 600, 400);
        return painelX;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Teste t = new Teste();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque você está contando o número de linhas do seu `TableModel`, quando na verdade deveria contar o numero de linhas que foram filtradas da busca pelo seu `RowSorter`, afinal, ao fazer uma pesquisa, nada é alterado no TableModel, e sim, no `RowSorter`.

Outro detalhe importante, você deve contar o numéro de linhas após a pesquisa ter sido efetuada, ou seja, após aplicar o filtro através do `setRowFilter()`, e não antes.

Veja o código abaixo corrigido:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Teste extends JFrame {

    private String[] colunas
            = {"Country", "Capital", "Population in Millions", "Democracy"};

    private Object[][] dados = {
        {"USA", "Washington DC", 280, true},
        {"Canada", "Ottawa", 32, true},
        {"United Kingdom", "London", 60, true},
        {"Germany", "Berlin", 83, true},
        {"France", "Paris", 60, true},
        {"Norway", "Oslo", 4.5, true},
        {"India", "New Delhi", 1046, true}
    };

    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(dados, colunas);
    private JTable tabela = new JTable(model);

    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(tabela.getModel());

    private JTextField barraPesquisa = new JTextField();
    private JButton botao = new JButton("OK");

    private JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public Teste() {
        add(x());
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JComponent x() {
        JPanel painelX = new JPanel();
        painelX.setLayout(null);

        painelX.add(barraPesquisa);
        barraPesquisa.setBounds(20, 10, 270, 27);
        painelX.add(botao);
        botao.setBounds(300, 10, 65, 27);

        barraPesquisa.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = barraPesquisa.getText();

                //model.setRowCount(0); // limpar as linhas

                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                    model.getRowCount();
                }
                label.setText(rowSorter.getViewRowCount() + " resultados encontrados");
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = barraPesquisa.getText();
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
                label.setText(rowSorter.getViewRowCount() + " resultados encontrados");
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            }
        });

        tabela.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

        painelX.add(tabela);
        tabela.setBounds(5, 100, 500, 150);

        painelX.add(label);
        label.setBounds(10, 250, 150, 30);
        label.setText(model.getRowCount() + " resultados encontrados!");

        painelX.setBounds(1, 1, 600, 400);
        return painelX;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Teste t = new Teste();
    }
}
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]