# Busca em JTable não retorna como esperado

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou com um bug que não estou entendendo. A ideia é simples, eu deveria digitar um valor em um campo e ele me retornar na tabela, isso acontece, porem quando clico em cima do valor encontrado na busca ele me seleciona o primeiro valor dentro da tabela

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

import br.sp.mogi.imperiocongelados.model.Client;
import br.sp.mogi.imperiocongelados.model.tables.ModelTableClient;

public class Teste extends JFrame 
{
    public Teste() 
    {
        inicializarComponentes();
        inicializarEventos();
    }

    private void inicializarComponentes() 
    {
        setTitle("Teste");
        setSize(490, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        // Search
        JTextField txtSearchForCode = new JTextField();
        txtSearchForCode.setToolTipText("Busca por codigo");
        txtSearchForCode.setLocation(10, 10);
        txtSearchForCode.setSize(50, 25);
        add(txtSearchForCode);

        // Table
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        scroll.setLocation(10, txtSearchForCode.getY() + txtSearchForCode.getHeight() + 1);
        scroll.setSize(470, 540);
        scroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(scroll);

    }

    private void searchForCode()
    {
        ModelTableClient tableClient = (ModelTableClient) table.getModel();

        final TableRowSorter<ModelTableClient> sorter = new TableRowSorter<ModelTableClient>(tableClient);

        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        String searchForCode = txtSearchForCode.getText();

        if(searchForCode.length() == 0)
        {
            sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        }
        else
        {
            try 
            {
                RowFilter<ModelTableClient, Object> rf = null;

                try
                {
                    rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(searchForCode, 0);
                }
                catch(java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e)
                {
                    return;
                }

                sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro de busca por codigo", "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    public void completeFields()
    {
        txtName.setText(selectedClient.getName());

        String dateText = dateFormat.format(selectedClient.getRegistrationDate());
        ftRegistrationDate.setText(dateText);

        ftDocument.setText(selectedClient.getDocument());

        ftZipCode.setText(selectedClient.getZipCode());
        txtState.setText(selectedClient.getState());
        txtCity.setText(selectedClient.getCity());
        txtNeighborhood.setText(selectedClient.getNeighborhood());
        txtStreet.setText(selectedClient.getStreet());
        ftNumber.setText(selectedClient.getNumber());

        ftLandLine.setText(selectedClient.getLandline());
        ftCellphone.setText(selectedClient.getCellPhone());

        ftRoute.setText(selectedClient.getRoute());
    }

    private void inicializarEventos() 
    {
        // Select row on table
            table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) 
                {
                        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                        if(row >= 0 && row < clientList.size())
                        {
                            selectedClient = clientList.get(row);
                            completeFields();
                        }
                }
            });

            // Search
            txtSearchForCode.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
            {
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
                {
                    searchForCode();
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Aplicar filtros em uma JTable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166973/aplicar-filtros-em-uma-jtable)

Comment: Relacionada: [Implementar um “contador” de resultados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189793/28595)

Comment: Adicionei o código completo do visualizar clientes

Comment: O meu realiza a busca, mas quando clico em cima ele puxa o primeiro resultado, não o que eu busquei

Comment: Esse código não é um **[mcve]**, possui dependencias de outras classes. Remova todas as dependencias, deixe apenas o necessario para que o erro seja reproduzivel. Leia como fazer isso no link que eu citei. Aproveite e leia as respostas que linkei, possuem exemplos de filtros identico ao que você está fazendo.

Comment: Acho que agora está o necessário, deixei apenas as funções que ele precisa pra realizar a busca e o código com o nome dos campos junto com o construtor

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65513/discussion-between-rodrigo-prado-and-articuno).

Comment: O codigo continua com dependencias, você so cortou os imports. Por favor, leia o primeiro link para aprender a forneçar um exemplo minimo, completo e verificavel.

Comment: Eu li e deixei apenas as dependências que a busca utiliza que é do modelo da tabela

Comment: ***Recomece do zero. Crie um novo programa, e só inclua nele o necessário para reproduzir o problema.***

Comment: não sou especialista, acho que é isso ai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não forneceu um *exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável*, mas suspeito que a causa seja conflito de índices do filtro da tabela e do modelo.

Ao fazer um filtro em uma tabela, você precisa converter o indice do filtro para o equivalente ao indice do model para poder recuperar a linha filtrada corretamente:

```
int rowSel = suaTable.getSelectedRow();//pega o indice da linha na tabela
int indexRowModel = suaTable.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(rowSel);//converte pro indice do model
```

Mais informações você pode ler nos links que deixei relacionados na pergunta e nestra [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/139890/28595), ou fornecendo um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) corretamente para que seja possivel analisar melhor o problema.

Comment: Funcionou como esperado, me quebro um galho. Obrigado